# Why Zend autoloader require registering namespace, seems could be avoided

Tags: zend-framework, autoload

I would like to know why Zend autoloader require registering namespaces. At first it seems it could be avoided, so I would like to know what I am missing :

If I want to use an external class, I have to put in libraryFolder and when I use it, I have to reference its full name :

For example, if I want to use the class in /libraryFolder/myNamespace/package_name/Class/Name.php, I have to call \myNamespace\package_name\Class_Name.

So why do I have to register myNamespace ? Zend should find the class without registering thanks to the full name \myNamespace\package_name\Class_Name being given.

I know I am missing something but not sure what.

Comment: because he dosnt now the root for \myNamespace\... . maybe it is in vendor and maybe it is in some other directory

Comment: @icrew, according to Zend practice, there is only one library folder called "library" :) 

(http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend+Framework+Default+Project+Structure+-+Wil+Sinclair)

And anyway, registering does not tell where the class root folder is, it just gives the namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a effort to put some limits on how far the autoloader will look for a class, however if you want the autoloader to load anything simply set : `$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);`

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html